# Pyqt get qlistwidget item when widget inside itemwidget is clicked

Tags: python-2.7

this is the current application looks like this:

It has a Qlistwidget `listWidget_links` where each item has own itemwidget set (combobox, checkbox, button, ...) Now I came upon a problem that neither google or I can solve.

If the user presses the **create** button or any other item's itemwidget how do I let a method know **the item** the widget was pressed changed inside.

```
item_widget.comboBox_type.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.itemupdate_linktype)
item_widget.checkBox_hide.stateChanged.connect(self.itemupdate_hidden)


cbox = self.sender() # gives the widget that released the signal
cbox.parent() #I discovered by a lucky try, returns NodeLinkItemWidgetUI.Ui_Form object which is a item's itemwidget
```

Here is how items get created to in order to understand the program structure better:

```
def createNewLink(self, nodename, nodeclass):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget_links)
        item_widget = NodeLinkItemWidgetUI.Ui_Form(nodename, nodeclass)

        item.nodename = nodename
        item.nodeclass = nodeclass

        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(130, 160))
        self.listWidget_links.addItem(item)
        self.listWidget_links.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)
```

Edit: solved setting the variable item_widget.item = item seems to work, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: ok, setting the variable item_widget.item = item seems to work, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: provide a [mcve]